# Compare some atomic exchange other

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

what I need to do today with atomic operations is rather tricky and I'd like some help. In a nutshell, I would like to perform the following operation atomically:

```
/* begin of atomicity */
if (--counter == 0)
{
   Widget* widget = nullptr;

   swap(some_widget, widget);

   /* end of atomicity */

   // use local 'widget' here
}
/* end of atomicity */
```

I am aware of C++11 atomics and intrinsics. The previous code is only *pseudo* and is intended to show what I would like to happen atomically. I know one solution would be to make counter have a "Transition" state (example 0xFFFFFFFF) and only change its value moving to this transition first and then to a new value: it would essentially be analogous to a spinlock. Any idea on how to do this *efficiently* (i.e. no spinlocks, no mutexes, and possibly no waits)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There're two **/\* end of atomicity \*/**, which one the the *true* end? I doubt there any way to execute multiple statement in atomic without using lock.

Comment: Also, you don't want to *delete* `some_widget`, you just want to assign it to `nullptr`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C++11, you want to do an atomic fetch_and_add, then work with the results.

For example:

```
std::atomic<int> counter = 20;

if (counter.fetch_sub(1) == 1) /* return value is old value */
{
   Widget* widget = nullptr;
   swap(some_widget, widget);
}
```

If the counter is used across threads, we need to ensure that compiler and hardware do not mess up the memory ordering. 
The default ordering for `std::atomic<>.fetch_sub()` is `std::memory_order_seq_cst` which will do just fine, but if you want to win on e.g. ARM64, you can reduce to `std::memory_order_acquire`.

To make the swap operation fit in the above scheme, we do need a lock.
Interestingly, this fits the "double checked lock" pattern, which is frowned upon by some but is rather useful here - for most operations you will not suffer from the lock, but when it counts, it's there.
Here's how:

```
std::atomic<int> counter = 20;
std::mutex  counterLock;
std::atomic<Widget*> some_widget;

...

if (counter.load(std::memory_order_acquire) > 5) /* first check whether we're "close enough" */
{
  /* only lock when needed */
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> templock(counterLock); /* free lock whenever we exit this scope */
  if (counter.fetch_sub(1) == 1) /* return value is old value */
  {
    Widget* oldwidgetpr = some_widget.exchange(nullptr, std::memory_ordering_release);
    /* do whatever you need to do with the oldwidgetptr */
  }
}
else
  counter.fetch_sub(1);
```

Comment: This is exactly the code I have right now, but the decrement and the swap are not at atomic. Right after decrementing, some other thread might change that 'some_widget' pointer and I have a race.

Comment: In that case, why not go for the "double checked lock" approach? it will allow for quick decrements without locks, yet save you from swapping issues. I'll code it and then post it.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the above.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I am afraid this doesn't answer the question. First it's using a mutex and is unacceptable for what I intend to do. Second you first check whether counter > 1, then check tha counter.fetch_sub(1) == 1 is true. What if counter is 1 and nothing else happens? The first if fails and the counter is never decremented.

Comment: I'm aware my code isn't complete, but I'm mostly trying to show the concept. By first performing a check, you take the lock/unlock of the mutex out of the main code path - that should improve performance considerably and reduce the need for a "I cannot use locks" statement. If you really cannot use locks, you'll probably need a different mechanism altogether where you reduce or eliminate the interactivity between threads. I'll need a more input to help you in that case.